# Converting JSON data to Tabular in Snowflake

Tags: sql, json, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have this JSON raw data that is injected to Snowflake via Kafka from devices. I am trying to convert some of the values to a table using Snowflake's Dynamic Table (so basiacally I just need to fix the SELECT statement).

This is the snapshot of the JSON data, the column name is RECORD_CONTENT.

```
{
  "enterprise": "xx",
  "genericTrap": x,
  "pduBerEncoded": "xxx",
  "pduRawBytes": "xxxx",
  "peerAddress": "xx",
  "peerPort": "xx",
  "securityName": "xxx",
  "specificTrap": xx,
  "sysUpTime": xxxx,
  "variables": [
    {
      "oid": "column_a",
      "type": "octetString",
      "value": "xxx
    },
    {
      "oid": "column_b",
      "type": "integer",
      "value": "xxx"
    }
  ]
}
```

the expected output is this:

column_a | column_b | specific_trap

xxx | xxx | xx

For other devices which I only need to parse Variables, I have been able to do with this basic query:

```
SELECT 
  MAX(CASE WHEN f.value:oid::STRING = 'column_a' THEN f.value:value::STRING END) AS column_a,
  MAX(CASE WHEN f.value:oid::STRING = 'column_b' THEN f.value:value::STRING END) AS column_b
FROM table_a,
    LATERAL FLATTEN(input => RECORD_CONTENT:variables) f
GROUP BY
    f.seq
```

However, introducing the **specific trap** column proves to be a bit challenging for me. Can you please help me?

Thank you in advanced.

Edit: specific trap only has 2 values, either 1 or 2. Hence, groupping by specific trap is not possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably need to address one task at a time. First, extract the fields a table with the array variables into rows, and then transpose them, for example:

```
with table_a(col) as (
    select
        parse_json(
            '{
  "enterprise": "xx",
  "genericTrap": "1",
  "pduBerEncoded": "xxx",
  "pduRawBytes": "xxxx",
  "peerAddress": "xx",
  "peerPort": "xx",
  "securityName": "xxx",
  "specificTrap": "1",
  "sysUpTime": "xxxx",
  "variables": [
    {
      "oid": "column_a",
      "type": "octetString",
      "value": "vala"
    },
    {
      "oid": "column_b",
      "type": "integer",
      "value": "valb"
    }
  ]
}'
        ) as variant
)
select
    --seq,
    any_value(specifictrap) specifictrap,
    max(case oid when 'column_a' then oid_val else null end)  column_a,
    max(case oid when 'column_b' then oid_val else null end)  column_b
    
from
    (
        select
            f.seq seq,
            col:specificTrap::VARCHAR specifictrap,
            f.value:oid::VARCHAR oid,
            f.value:value::VARCHAR oid_val
        from
            table_a,
            lateral FLATTEN(input => table_a.col:variables::ARRAY) f
    ) t
group by
    seq;
```

On the first step you produce an intermediate table like this:

| SEQ | SPECIFICTRAP | OID | OID_VAL |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | column_a | vala |
| 1 | 1 | column_b | valb |

Then, it's easy enough to transpose the table to get the desired result.

Answer (score 0):

select
max(case when rc.value:oid::string='column_a' then rc.value:value::string end) column_a
,max(case when rc.value:oid::string='column_b' then rc.value:value::string end) column_b
,record_content:specificTrap::string as specific_trap

from json_data a,
lateral flatten(input=>record_content:variables) rc
group by specific_trap

Comment: It is not possible to be groupped by specific trap, since specific trap only has a value of either 1 or 2. So grouping it will only return 2 rows instead.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).